# Get result asynchronous function without promise

Tags: angularjs, function, synchronous

Is it possible to get a result function without return a promise ?

For example, I have a function who need to return a value and not a promise:

```
getItem: function (item) {
    AppStorage.fetch(item, function (item) {
        return item;
    });
}
```

This code doesn't works cause the result is undefined cause it doesn't wait the function response.
I have to call the function: "AppStorage.fetch" with a synchrone mode.

Do you have some suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback functions.

```
getItem: function (item, callback) {
    AppStorage.fetch(item, function (item) {
        callback(item);
    });
}
```

Call:

```
getItem(item, function(item) {

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the getItem provided from an external lib so I can't change the call.

Comment: Did you try something like:

getItem: function (item) {
 
    var itemResult = undefined;
   
    AppStorage.fetch(item, function (item) {

     itemResult = item;
     
        return item;
    });

    while(itemResult == undefined);

    return itemResult;
}